# Unable to access local variables interactively after Python error

Tags: python, interactive

If running a python script in interactive (`-i`) mode, to help with debugging, how is it possible to access the stack frame at the point where an error happens?

Script

```
# pytest.py
def foo(x):
    assert False

foo(24601)
```

Command session

```
D:\>python.exe -i pytest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pytest.py", line 4, in <module>
    foo(3)
  File "pytest.py", line 2, in foo
    assert False
AssertionError
>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

How would one access the value of x where the assertion failed in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Use the python debugger - https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

```
def foo(x):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()   #add this line to set a breakpoint
    assert False
```

(You dont need it -i flag)

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without having to add the above line of code to every function I want to debug?

Answer (score 1):

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52215-get-more-information-from-tracebacks/

Python debugger answer sounds good. But, in case you want to try 'something else'.
I've found this thing - and it looks like the answer you're looking for. You can use the traceback module to build a function printing out the locals, frame by frame, in the event of an error. From there, I guess you can extract the data from the log.

As noted in the example from the link:

```
import sys, traceback

def print_exc_plus():
    """
    Print the usual traceback information, followed by a listing of all the
    local variables in each frame.
    """
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    while 1:
        if not tb.tb_next:
            break
        tb = tb.tb_next
    stack = []
    f = tb.tb_frame
    while f:
        stack.append(f)
        f = f.f_back
    stack.reverse()
    traceback.print_exc()
    print "Locals by frame, innermost last"
    for frame in stack:
        print
        print "Frame %s in %s at line %s" % (frame.f_code.co_name,
                                             frame.f_code.co_filename,
                                             frame.f_lineno)
        for key, value in frame.f_locals.items():
            print "\t%20s = " % key,
            #We have to be careful not to cause a new error in our error
            #printer! Calling str() on an unknown object could cause an
            #error we don't want.
            try:
                print value
            except:
                print "<ERROR WHILE PRINTING VALUE>"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #A simplistic demonstration of the kind of problem this approach can help
    #with. Basically, we have a simple function which manipulates all the
    #strings in a list. The function doesn't do any error checking, so when
    #we pass a list which contains something other than strings, we get an
    #error. Figuring out what bad data caused the error is easier with our
    #new function.

    data = ["1", "2", 3, "4"] #Typo: We 'forget' the quotes on data[2]
    def pad4(seq):
        """
        Pad each string in seq with zeros, to four places. Note there
        is no reason to actually write this function, Python already
        does this sort of thing much better.
        Just an example.
        """
        return_value = []
        for thing in seq:
            return_value.append("0" * (4 - len(thing)) + thing)
        return return_value

    #First, show the information we get from a normal traceback.print_exc().
    try:
        pad4(data)
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
    print
    print "----------------"
    print

    #Now with our new function. Note how easy it is to see the bad data that
    #caused the problem. The variable 'thing' has the value 3, so we know
    #that the TypeError we got was because of that. A quick look at the
    #value for 'data' shows us we simply forgot the quotes on that item.
    try:
        pad4(data)
    except:
        print_exc_plus()
```

After executing the code, I got the output containing local variables and their values!

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
                __name__ =  __main__
                    data =  ['1', '2', 3, '4']
                 __doc__ =  None
          print_exc_plus =  <function print_exc_plus at 0x7ffb8ee86668>

Frame pad4 in /home/robert.sawicki/PycharmProjects/python_challenge/test.py at line 55
                   thing =  3
            return_value =  ['0001', '0002']
                     seq =  ['1', '2', 3, '4']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the python debugger directly in interactive mode

D:>python.exe -m pdb pytest.py

Use

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pdb` in the interactive Python shell too - you just have to encapsulate your code in a proper function:

```
bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground$ cat pytest.py
# pytest.py
def foo(x):
    assert False

def main():
    print foo(24601)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pytest
>>> import pdb
>>> pdb.runcall(pytest.main)
> /home/bruno/Work/playground/pytest.py(6)main()
-> print foo(24601)
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /home/bruno/Work/playground/pytest.py(2)foo()
-> def foo(x):
(Pdb) l
  1     # pytest.py
  2  -> def foo(x):
  3         assert False
  4     
  5     def main():
  6         print foo(24601)
  7     
  8     
  9     if __name__ == "__main__":
 10         main()
[EOF]
(Pdb) n
> /home/bruno/Work/playground/pytest.py(3)foo()
-> assert False
(Pdb) !x
24601
(Pdb) c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 1248, in runcall
    return Pdb().runcall(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 436, in runcall
    res = func(*args, **kwds)
  File "pytest.py", line 6, in main
    print foo(24601)
  File "pytest.py", line 3, in foo
    assert False
AssertionError
>>>
```